# Lwip w/ Raw Api - Unefficiency Issue

Tags: tcp, stm32, ethernet, lwip

I'm working on lwip with using STM32H7 as a Tcp client, I also tried on STM32F4. According to my design, I need to transmit a packet with 1 ms time period to host, continuously. Also host sends a packet with 2 ms time period. So I created the software design according to these request.

But my code does not do job on time. For example, size of my packet is 40 bytes. Sometimes it is sending to host 400 bytes, sometimes 200 bytes, even if I use `tcp_output()`. Sometimes it is waiting 500-1000ms, without doing anything. When it does not send on time, queue length exceeds, and I'm gettin `ERR_MEM` as it is. But what I need here is to only send 40 bytes of data on. By the way, I observed the transmission time, it takes only 3-4 us with 100Mbps. I tried also in 10Mbps, it takes 40-50  us, but the result did not change.

I'm having same trouble in receive process. I'm getting the packet with  `recv` callback function, but it is also missing most of packages, if I send periodically from host. Sometimes it is taking on time, sometimes doing nothing.

I think there is no problem in my transmit and received callback function, they are very simple, but I want to share here.

```
uint8_t tcpClientTransmit(const unsigned char *p_data, uint8_t len)
{

    err_t err_ret;

    err_ret = tcp_write(m_tcpPcbClient, p_data, len, 0); // Queues up data to be sent.

    if(err_ret == ERR_OK)
    {
        if(tcp_output(m_tcpPcbClient) != ERR_OK)                                    // Force to sent.
        {
            return 1;
        }
        else
        {
            return 0;
        }
    }

    else
    {
        return 1;    //error occured
    }
}



uint8_t tcpReceivedCallback(void *arg, struct tcp_pcb *tpcb, struct pbuf *p, err_t err)
{
    if(p == NULL)
    {
      g_ethernetConnected = false;

      tcpClientDisconnect();
    }

    else
    {
      tcp_recved(tpcb, p->tot_len);

      pbuf_free(p);

      parseProcess((unsigned char*)p->payload);
    }

    return err_ret;
 }
```

I've been stuck here for long days. I've seen various similar issues in questions, but I could not see the solution, or they do not solve my problem. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I’m not familiar with lwIP., but did you disable Nagle algorithm ? Also pbuf_free BEFORE parsing the payload seems wrong.

Comment: Actually, I had tried to disable nagle algorithm, but I guess I could not disable in proper place. When I tried it again now, it worked! It needed to disable eftsoon after new tcp pcb is created.

Comment: When nagle is disabled, most of problem is solved. But still sometimes sends 2-3 packet at once. This means that the host misses packets while parsing.  Even after a certain period of time, the error status turns completely to ERR_MEM on client side, and conncetion is down.

Comment: Did you fix the use-after-free bug in tcpReceivedCallback ? Also should improve your host code being aware that TCP is basically a STREAM protocol. You simply can’t rely on receiving the data exactly as the peer might have sent it. Alternatively use a datagram protocol like UDP.

Comment: Yes I fixed it but I could not understand, it was working in wrong way, I was accesing the payload after freeing all time. Can pbuf_free not free the pbuf on time, i do not know. thank you. Secndly, I aware that, but I wanted to take advantage of the good sides of tcp :) It seems that I will pass to UDP. Thanks for your helping.

Comment: The bad thing of use-after-free bugs is that the freed memory might be still untouched/not yet reused for a while and the code SEEMS to work well. Until things slightly change and the application crashes or you encounter strange, buggy behavior.